# How to extract type from nested array in type declaration?

Tags: typescript

I have a generated type that looks like this:

```
export type GetUserWithMembershipsQuery = {
  getUser: {
    __typename: 'User';
    id: string;
    memberships: {
      __typename: 'ModelUserMembershipConnection';
      items: Array<{
        __typename: 'UserMembership';
        id: string;
        createdOnDate: string | null;
        renewedOnDate: string | null;
        expiresOnDate: string | null;
        membershipPhotoFileName: string | null;
      } | null> | null;
    } | null;
  } | null;
};
```

I know I can get the type of the getUser by saying `GetUserWithMembershipQuery['getUser']`.

I'm wondering how I can extract the type of the items array within the memberships object from within that type, or if it's possible?

I would like to end up with something like:

`type ItemType = GetUserWithMembershipQuery['getUser']['memberships']['items'][0]`

Where the resulting type is:

```
{
  __typename: 'UserMembership';
  id: string;
  createdOnDate: string | null;
  renewedOnDate: string | null;
  expiresOnDate: string | null;
  membershipPhotoFileName: string | null;
} | null
```

I have tried going down one more level by using `GetUserWithMembershipQuery['getUser']['memberships']`, but I get an error saying that the 'Property memberships does not exist on type ...'

Is this because `getUser` or `memberships` is possibly null?  Is there a way I can extract this type?  Any help pointing to resources with how I can better understand this would be a great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that  under `strictNullChecks` if a type is in a union with `null` then no members will be accessible. This is the case both for value and type expressions. You can still get the type but you need to exclude `null` from the union using the `Exclude` conditional type. The syntax becomes a bit too convoluted to write in just one line so I broke it down in several steps :

```
type getUser = Exclude<GetUserWithMembershipsQuery['getUser'], null>
type memberships = Exclude<getUser['memberships'], null>
type items = Exclude<memberships['items'], null>
type item =  Exclude<items[number], null>
```